# Load lib with higher version than default in Grails and Geronimo

Tags: servlets, grails, classloader, geronimo

I'm using Grails 2.1 and Geronimo Server 2.1.8. Geronimo has HttpClient version 3.1 in default , my application use Grails and HttpClient 4.3.

So I can run it on local use run-app, but after build to war file and deploy on server. It can't run anything because conflict between HttpClient 4.3(my application) and 3.1(default on Geronimo).

I tested with pure servlet project and add HttpClient 4.3 to lib, then build war file and deploy, everything work fine, don't have any conflict between HttpClient 4.3(pure servlet application) and 3.1(default on Geronimo).

Here my solution is use hidden class in Geronimo config for hidden default version in Geronimo but I think it's not best solution. I think it's problem of Grails class loader. Everyone know about that?

Thanks in advance!